# All my Assert.isTrue testing seems to be passing, im a bit skeptical about how efficient it's to test with asert.isTrue and assert.isFalse

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, chai

Is Assert.isTrue efficient for testing solidity functions, all my testing are passing and I'm a bit skeptical about its efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like a question.
I can tell you forge tests with assertTrue works. Please share your code if you want some help.